# Type "inout Uint8" does not conform to protocol "intererLiteralConvertible" when writing a for loop

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to write a `for` loop like so:

```
for var I = 2; I < Integer; ++1{}
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Type'inout Uint8" does not conform to protocol "intererLiteralConvertible"
> ```

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: ++1 should be ++I ..

Comment: Thank you.  Just shows I need to pay a little more attention.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var stop=5

for var i = 2; i < stop; i++
{
    NSLog("\(i)")
}
```

A few pointers based on the code you posted (`for var I = 2; I < Integer; ++1{}`):

1. `I` should really be lowercase.
2. `++1` is ambigious - the app doesn't know what to add to, and thus that causes an error. `i++` or `i+=1` or `i=i+1` would work here, I used `i++` because that seemed to be what you were trying to do.
3. `Integer` is a poor name for a variable. You should use something more descriptive, like `stop` as I have here.

Answer (score 0):

```
let end = 10

for var i = 2; i < end; ++i {
    // do something
}
```